# Asp vNext Sessions

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to store and use Session variables in ASP MVC 6 but I couldn't find a way to do it .

After I install Microsoft.AspNet.Session package I get an Internal Server Error

```
System.MissingMethodException
Method not found: 'Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceDescriptor Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.ServiceDescriber.Instance(System.Object)'.
at Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.KlrHttpApplication.ApplicationStart(IHttpApplication application) 
at Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.HttpApplicationBase.InvokeApplicationStart(IHttpApplication application)
```

Also, the code for Session implementation in older ASP MVC versions doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The `MissingMethodException` is very common when you combine different versions of the packages. For example, `Beta2` and `Beta3` packages.

Please check your `project.json` file and make sure that that all packages come from the same release.

Also, the KRE (renamed to DNX recently) must be from the same release as the packages.

Comment: I used beta 1 for everything and it worked . Can you also tell me how to store and retrieve session variables ? I found some samples but app.UseSession() method doesn't exist .